# Is there a way to track https sockets used/available in aws sdk v3?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, amazon-dynamodb, out-of-memory, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm loading a boatload of data to DynamoDB in batch everyday using an AWS lambda and the aws javascript sdk v3. The lambda pulls the data from a Snowflake DB and aggregates it into DynamoDB objects. I'm trying to maximize throughput so that the process finishes quickly. But I'm sending the data so fast that the available sockets max out and the lambda runs out of memory as the requests I'm sending to Dynamo queue up while waiting for an available socket.

I tried some different values for maxSockets landing on about 350. (500 maxed out memory immediately) But I'm still queueing requests so I'm still maxing out memory and failing. I'm wondering if there is a way to track when sockets are maxed out and pause the stream until some are available but I can't find anything in the aws sdk or nodejs documentation that will do that.